# Uso de "así que" y "por eso"

Tags: gramática

> "El seto era demasiado alto _____ el jardinero lo recortó.

Esta frase es de Josefa Martin Garcia.

Creo que debe insertar "por eso" en vez de "así que". Por qué es mejor o correcto usar `así que`?

Comment: Así que es el conector consecutivo más común de todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambos cumplen exactamente la misma función. Son un conector de tipo "consecutivo", es decir, su función es encabezar una frase que indica la consecuencia de lo dicho anteriormente. Las siguientes oraciones son equivalentes:

> El seto era demasiado alto, **así que** el jardinero lo recortó.
>
> El seto era demasiado alto, **por eso** el jardinero lo recortó.
>
> El seto era demasiado alto, **por lo tanto** el jardinero lo recortó.
>
> El seto era demasiado alto, **en consecuencia** el jardinero lo recortó.
>
> El seto era demasiado alto, **por ende** el jardinero lo recortó.

También se usan con mucha más frecuencia **y** y **entonces**, que son conectores con una función más general (de tipo "copulativo", simplemente "pegan" frases y el receptor del mensaje adivina la relación). Así que en el habla coloquial vas a escuchar:

> El seto era demasiado alto, **entonces** el jardinero lo recortó.
>
> El seto era demasiado alto, **y** el jardinero lo recortó.

Fíjate dónde va la coma (**,**). Va antes del conector o encerrándolo, no después como en tu ejemplo.

Comment: Los segundos ejemlos no significan lo mismo. En los segundos ejemplos que pones no se entiende la relación entre la altura de los setos y la acción de cortarlos. Siplemente son altos y el jardinero los poda, podría darse el caso que los setos eran altos porque así era el diseño original y el jardinero los recortó sin órdenes previas, no se "adivina" tan fácilmente si lo que se quieres es denotar que los cortó porque estaban largos.